# Clickable search icon in background

Tags: html, css

I have a search field with a search icon in the background. Here's the CSS:

```
    input[type=search] {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;

    background: #ededed url('$http://www.$domain/images/search-icon.png') no-repeat right 5px top 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 122px;
    font-size:16px;
     font-family: \"Lato\";
  font-weight: 300;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 10em;
    border-radius: 10em;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #7486BA;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #7486BA;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #7486BA;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #7486BA;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 122px;
}
}

input[type=search]:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #DEDEDE;
}
input[type=search]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #DEDEDE;
}
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<form id=\"search_form\" method=\"GET\" action=\"$http://www.$domain/\">
<input type=\"search\" id=\"search\" name=\"search\" placeholder=\"$search_placeholder\" class=\"awesomplete\" autocomplete=\"off\">
</form>
```

The form can only be submit by pressing enter button. What would be the easiest way to make the search icon clickable ?

I tried making a 30x30 anchor with relative positionning on top of the search icon but it wasn't working well

Comment: The easiest way would be to convert the search icon into a separate `button` element with `type="submit"`

Comment: What's with all the backslashes?

Comment: Regarding the backslashes, are you adding the html dynamically by code?

Comment: The code comes from a PHP file that outputs this HTML+CSS.. Just ignore the backslashes :P